# Is there anything like a 'recipe generator' for LEGO models?

Tags: instructions, software, set-database

For me, most of the fun of LEGO toys, is building new things from the instructions. Rebuilding things can be fun, but if I know I have certain bricks (or even sets), is there somewhere to cross-reference these with the content of other constructions/sets (official or otherwise)?

Comment: I would love to work on that algorithm.

Answer (score 52):

Yes there is! [Rebrickable.com](http://rebrickable.com/) is dedicated entirely to doing so. You can save time and import your LEGO collection from [Brickset.com](http://Brickset.com) (If you have an account). The site will then search for other sets and MOCs you can build from the bricks you have in your collection.

[image: Rebrickable search interface]

Answer (score 15):

If you want to know if you can build a certain set with the parts you have, you can have a look at set inventories on [Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/) or [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/)

You can also even enter a list of your own parts on Peeron and have it check it against existing sets, thus letting you know what you can build, or what you need to buy to build the set you want.