# What is the best way to sort LEGO bricks?

Tags: colour, organisation

I live in Hungary. I have tens of thousands of bricks at home. Over 1000 sets plus bricks. Most of the sets are sorted and packed separately, in their original boxes if they can with a box. Unfortunately some sets were mixed and kept in cardboard boxes. i. e.: 15 Harry Potter sets all mixed in a big box. The problem is that LEGO changed the colors in 2004. I must sort all parts according to color and type first. After that I can start putting the sets together from lists.

Is there a good way you know for physically sorting parts according to color, shape, etc?

Comment: This isn't directly an answer, but I encourage you to read the Evolution of LEGO Sorting: http://news.lugnet.com/storage/?n=707

Comment: Thanks a lot. I enjoyed it very much. One difference is that I stopped buying new sets. It is like quitting smoking. I managed it. At least for the last year or so.  I am planning to spend the rest of my summer sorting, boxing.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate but you should read this other question: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/6064