# Identification tool for LEGO parts

Tags: part-identification

I wounder if a lego part identification tool or POC already exist?

I would like to try to build a small POC software using a such recognition concept. Where should I look first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/550/13403 and/or https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/6064/13403 :-)

Comment: See also https://brickit.app/ - although details of the internal workings are rather scarce. And read https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-lego-image-recognition-using-virtual-data-and-yolov3-f12e0544012 too.

Answer (score 2):

[Instabrick](https://instabrick.org) has been around for a couple of years. That is the only product that I'm aware of that has actually made it to market, though plenty of other people have talked about building their own.