# How can I catalog my LEGO pieces?

Tags: organisation

I have a fairly large LEGO collection, but not large enough that I can build anything and everything, given instructions. It's already organized quite well, but how can I catalog the pieces I have so I can easily tell whether I can build something?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/102/is-there-anything-like-a-recipe-generator-for-lego-models) -- it's probably what you're trying to find.

Comment: @PeterDC That's helpful, but they only let you input pieces set by set, and most of my pieces don't come from sets (or if they did, I've long forgotten what sets they were). I'm looking for something that'll essentially let me build an inventory brick by brick.

Comment: Actually, if you have a [Rebrickable.com](http://www.rebrickable.com) account (I do), then you can add individual elements to a digital list of your collection. Also, it's free to sign up, so it's a pretty useful resource, in my opinion.

Comment: @PeterDC Thanks! Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: I guess not… I'll do it then.

Comment: Sorry about that, I haven't been on SE for several days due to school. Sorry again for not being able to respond.

Comment: @PeterDC Oh, no problem--please feel free to answer it yourself at any time, I'll be happy to remove my answer! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rebrickable.com offers the ability to add sets as well as individual pieces to your account.

[image]