# What to build with generic set of pieces

Tags: set-database

I have a good stock of used lego pieces, and planning to acquire more. The problem is that I am not sure what to build with them!

1. Is there a list of sets easy to build with basic pieces, without the necessity of weird very rare pieces?
2. If I had the patience of inputting every piece I obtain, is there any website/service that would list me sets that are buildable with those pieces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many here have commented on the site Rebrickable as being the "go to" for the sort of thing you are looking for:  https://rebrickable.com/

Previous related inquiry on this site:
[Is there anything like a 'recipe generator' for LEGO models?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/102/is-there-anything-like-a-recipe-generator-for-lego-models/545#545)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look, but that definitely looks like what I am looking for :)